# How to set custom permalink structure for uploaded media files

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

In my WP v6.1.1, my permalinks structure for posts is `www.example.com/%postname%/`.

With this my uploaded media files permalink URLs (not `File URL`) are taking away the slugs which we intended to use for actual posts.

With below code I wanted to rewrite the media (images) file permalink like `www.example.com/img/imagename/` without changing the default upload folder.

```
add_action('init', 'custom_init');

function custom_init() {

global $wp_rewrite;

$url_structure = '/img/%img_postname%/';

$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('attachment', $url_structure, false);
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%img_postname%", '([^/]+)', "attachment=");

}
```

In another `post_type_link` filter function, I am converting the variable `%img_postname%` into `post_name`.

However, my media permalink URLs still are `www.example.com/imagename` not `www.example.com/img/imagename`

Answer (score 0):

use the [`attachment_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/attachment_link/) hook.

```
function custom_attachment_link($url, $post_id){
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    return $post ? sprintf('%s/%s/%s/', home_url(), 'img', $post->post_name) : $url;
}
add_filter('attachment_link', 'custom_attachment_link', 10, 2);
```

**make sure to flush your rewrite rules when you are done by going to: Settings > Permalinks and clicking 'save changes'**